# Problem occurred when upgrading Spring Boot to 3.0.3 from 2.7.8

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Tried to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.3 from 2.7.8 and when i press "Load Gradle Changes" got this error :

A problem occurred configuring project ':nc-application:nc-application-web-plugin:nc-application-runtime'.

> Task with name 'bootRunMainClassName' not found in project ':nc-application:nc-application-web-plugin:nc-application-runtime'.

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Exception is:

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':nc-application:nc-application-web-plugin:nc-application-runtime'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:255)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:351)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:350)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:761)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$1(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$9(StateTransitionController.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:325)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:49)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:50)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$3(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$10(StateTransitionController.java:210)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:206)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getConfiguredModel(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withProjectsConfigured$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:143)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:139)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withProjectsConfigured(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.lambda$locateBuilderForTarget$0(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withToolingModels(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.withToolingModels(AbstractBuildState.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForDefaultTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getTarget(DefaultBuildController.java:157)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:101)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$5(StateTransitionController.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:136)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with name 'bootRunMainClassName' not found in project ':nc-application:nc-application-web-plugin:nc-application-runtime'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultTaskCollection.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultTaskCollection.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.named(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.named(DefaultTaskCollection.java:112)
    at org.springdoc.openapi.gradle.plugin.OpenApiGradlePlugin$apply$1.execute(OpenApiGradlePlugin.kt:26)
    at org.springdoc.openapi.gradle.plugin.OpenApiGradlePlugin$apply$1.execute(OpenApiGradlePlugin.kt:11)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:171)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
```

Gradle is configured in the following files :

build.gradle(nc-template-service)

```
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'info.solidsoft.pitest' version '1.9.0'
    id 'com.github.ksoichiro.console.reporter' version '0.6.3' apply true
    id 'com.avast.gradle.docker-compose' version '0.16.9'
}

def coloredStatus = { def resultType ->
    String ansiReset = "\u001B[0m"
    String ansiGreen = "\u001B[32m"
    String ansiRed = "\u001B[31m"
    String ansiYellow = "\u001B[33m"
    def status
    switch (resultType) {
        case TestResult.ResultType.SUCCESS:
            status = "$ansiGreen $resultType $ansiReset"
            break
        case TestResult.ResultType.FAILURE:
            status = "$ansiRed $resultType $ansiRed"
            break
        default:
            // TestResult.ResultType.SKIPPED
            status = "$ansiYellow $resultType $ansiReset"
            break
    }
    return status
}

subprojects {
    ext {
        bootVersion = '3.0.3'
        spockVersion = '2.1-groovy-3.0'
        springDepManagementVersion = '1.0.11.RELEASE'
        group = 'tech.company'
        gatlingVersion = '3.7.6'
        openApiVersion = '1.6.9'
        springCloudVersion = '2021.0.3'
        groovyVersion = '4.0.1'
        kafkaVersion = '2.8.8'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "groovy"
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

    apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/checkstyle.gradle')
    apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/codenarc.gradle')
    if (project.name.endsWith("runtime")) {
        apply from: rootDir.absolutePath + "/gradle/jacoco.gradle"
        apply from: rootDir.absolutePath + "/gradle/pitest.gradle"

        // Jacoco external task dependencies config
        test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport, reportCoverage
        jacocoTestReport.finalizedBy reportCoverage
    }

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

    compileTestGroovy {
        groovyClasspath = configurations.testCompileClasspath
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${bootVersion}"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:${bootVersion}"
        //    Swagger - Documentation
        implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:${openApiVersion}"
        implementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:${kafkaVersion}"
        //Upgrade to Spring Boot 3
//        runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator")
    }

    //Setup dependencies for build
    build.dependsOn checkstyleMain, checkstyleTest

    tasks.withType(Test) {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        // Failfast on first failure by using -PfailFast='true'
        failFast = project.hasProperty('failFast') && project.property('failFast') == 'true'
        testLogging {
            afterSuite { desc, result ->
                if (desc.className) {
                    String className = desc.className.split('\\.')[-1]
                    String passedTests = "${result.successfulTestCount}/${result.testCount}"
                    def duration = result.endTime - result.startTime
                    logger.quiet "[${className}]: ${passedTests} passed - ${duration}ms \t [${coloredStatus(result.resultType)}]"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/infra.gradle')
```

build.gradle(:nc-application:nc-application-web-plugin:nc-application-runtime)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'tech.company.gradle', name: 'nc-json-schema-generator-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.4'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${bootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin' version '1.3.4'
    id 'tech.company.json.schema' version '1.0.4'
}


group = 'tech.company'
version = '1.0.0'


configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
dependencies {
    //TODO: IMPORT ALL CHILD PROJECTS/PLUGINS HERE
    implementation project(':nc-application:nc-application-web-plugin:nc-application-api')
    implementation project(':nc-application:nc-separate-plugin:nc-separate-plugin-runtime')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'

    implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter:16.1.0'
    implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-core:16.1.0'
    implementation 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:6.2.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'redis.clients:jedis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'

    implementation 'com.trendyol:Jdempotent-core:1.1.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations
    compileOnly 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.0'


    //Database
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'


    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core:${spockVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-spring:${spockVersion}"

    runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator")
}

jsonSchema {
    compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    println sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    pretty true

    include "tech/company/**/messages/**.class"
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'tech.company.template.application.core.TemplateCoreApplication'
}

//bootRunMainClassName = 'tech.company.template.application.core.TemplateCoreApplication'

tasks.named('bootJar') {
//    mainClass = 'tech.company.template.application.core.TemplateCoreApplication'
    archiveFileName = "application.jar"
}

/*tasks.named('bootRun') {
    mainClass = 'tech.company.template.application.core.TemplateCoreApplication'
}*/
```

Comment: Did you try closing and opening your IDE?

Comment: As with all gradle issues, first, the usual...  open/close IDE (as suggested).  Try from CLI.  Delete build folder.  Try with a clean....  As for your specific error, the problem surrounded `bootRunMainClassName`, correct?  Is it still throwing that even when that line is commented out?  Also, in our SB 3.0.x project, we specify the main class via:  `springBoot.mainClass = "..."`, not with `bootRunMainClassName`.  But, if it's commented out, it must be NOT commented out somewhere else?

Comment: aboudirawas & User51, i closed and opened IntelliJ IDEA and the same problem persists.

Comment: @User51, there is a block of springBoot: 
`springBoot { 
   mainClass = 'tech.company.template.application.core.TemplateCoreApplication' 
}` 
. Even with that, the error is "Task with name 'bootRunMainClassName' not found in project"

Comment: Can you search your entire project.  I only see the string `bootRunMainClassName` once, but it is commented out.  Because it is referencing that as the error, it MUST be referenced SOMEWHERE other than comments.  Search all your `.gradle` and `.properties` files.  Also search all sub-projects.

Answer (score 3):

The key part of the stack trace is the following:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with name 'bootRunMainClassName' not found in project ':nc-application:nc-application-web-plugin:nc-application-runtime'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultTaskCollection.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultTaskCollection.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.named(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.named(DefaultTaskCollection.java:112)
    at org.springdoc.openapi.gradle.plugin.OpenApiGradlePlugin$apply$1.execute(OpenApiGradlePlugin.kt:26)
```

It shows that some code in `org.springdoc.openapi.gradle.plugin.OpenApiGradlePlugin` is looking for the task named `bootRunMainClassName` and it does not exist. The task does not exist when you upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0 due to [these changes to Spring Boot's Gradle plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30467).

The incompatibility with Spring Boot 3.0's Gradle plugin has been fixed in 1.6.0 of the SpringDoc OpenApi Gradle plugin. You can upgrade by changing the plugins declaration in your `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${bootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin' version '1.6.0'
    id 'tech.company.json.schema' version '1.0.4'
}
```